# Nesting preg_replace functions while escaping tokens

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the 'e' modifier in preg_replace to search for a given string.  Then I need it to look within that string for individual matches using another preg_replace statement:

```
$str = "This is FOO.";
$str = preg_replace('/(foo)/ie', "x$1", $str);
echo $str;
```

This will generate: `This is xFOO.`
Now I need to nest. (I'm nesting because I need to match an unknown number of groups into separate tokens which is not possible with a single preg_replace statement as discussed elsewhere on this forum.  I've obviously simplified this code to focus on my question).

```
$str = "This is FOO.";
$str = preg_replace('/(foo)/ie', "preg_replace('/(\w)/i','x$1','$1')", $str);
echo $str;
```

I need this to generate `This is xFxOxO.`
But instead it generates `This is xFOOxFOOxFOO.`

When php evaluates the second line of code, it's replacing both $1 tokens with the matched string `foo`.  I need it to ignore the first $1 token because that is supposed to be evaluated by the inner preg_replace statement. How can I escape the first $1 token so that it won't be evaluated by the outside preg_replace statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can trick the parser with something like

```
$str = preg_replace('/(foo)/ie', "preg_replace('/(\w)/i','x$'.'1','$1')", $str);
```

but, honestly, it looks totally ugly. You might want to tell us more about the problem, i'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: Yes, that worked nicely.  Just adding that `'.'` was enough to delay the evaluation of that token.  Thank you.  To answer your question, i'm using this to markup a text file into xml.  I was identifying a whole row with <row> tags, then identifying elements within it with <heading> tags.